# Вставка картинки в AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно вставить изображение в сам текст AlertDialog?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода [.setView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html?hl=ru#setView(android.view.View)) класса AlertDialog.Builder.

Можно программно:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_ID);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(image).create();
```

Можно предварительно создать макет, содержащий ImageView:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_with_image, null)).create();
```

Comment: А можно ли как-то эту картинку вставить в определенное место текста?

Comment: Как макет сделаете, так она и будет расположена.